# How to create a jQuery class plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I know the heading might be a little off or not be meaningful at all, but I have been meaning to make a jQuery plugin. The normal way of a chained function I know but how to make it such that it is initialised inform of a class or a new object, for example, a PNotify plugin, this is how it is initialised

```
new PNotify({
    title: 'Regular Notice',
    text: 'Check me out! I\'m a notice.'
});
```

So I want my plugin to be initialised the same, how do I go about it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this link](https://github.com/shayanypn/GENS-Javascript-Boilerplate) it's a js base plugin structure

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.GENSPlugin = function() {

        // Global element references, to reference piece of plugin anywhere
        this.someElement = null;

        // Default Options
        var defaults = {
            firstOption: true,
            secondOption: 1
        }
        // Create options by extending defaults with the passed in arguments
        if (arguments[0] && typeof arguments[0] === "object") {
            this.options = extendDefaults(defaults, arguments[0]);
        }
        this.init();
    }
    // Public Method
    GENSPlugin.prototype.init = function() {
    }
    // Private Methods
    function somePrivateMethod() {
    }
    // Extend default Options
    function extendDefaults(defaults, properties) {
        var property;
        for (property in properties) {
            if (properties.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                defaults[property] = properties[property];
            }
        }
        return defaults;
    }
}());
var GENSplugin = new GENSPlugin({
    firstOption: false,
    secondOption: 5
});
```

Comment: Thanks, just saw it and that really helped

Comment: but one question though, where is the prototype in `GENSPlugin.prototype.init` coming from, because I would want to implement functions associated with it too and there is an init in that so i assumed init is a function that can be called but why the word prototype, like is it a keyword or just a user defined word?

Comment: @lulliezy please have a look at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp), it you still have problem, i am here to solve

Comment: @lulliezy your wellcome,

Comment: And also, I just wanna be sure about this, when you use the 'this' keyword, the variable will only be accessible inside that function right, or thats just that it can be accessed using the dot notation? @Shayan

Comment: @lulliezy `this` get the access of  `GENSPlugin` class.

Comment: This boilerplate fails if you have a plugin with no options. this.options is only defined if you pass in an argument object

Answer (score 1):

JS functions can be object constructors by default. For example:

```
function PNotify (params) {
  this.title = params.title;
  this.text  = params.text;

  // Do something jquery related here
}
```

You could call simple call it as:

```
var pnotify = new PNotify({ title: "hello", text: "world" })
```

You could learn more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)